# Flask pass the variable to url_for in html

Tags: html, file, variables, flask, audio

I am creating file which have a random number as a name.I pass return it to html file via Flask. But I dont know how to get returned name in html. It return like variable name not string of inside of the variable.

**Flask code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import inference

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/sentez", methods = ["POST"])
def sentez():
    if request.method == "POST":
        metin = request.form["metin"]
        created_audio, file_path = inference.create_model(metin)
        return render_template("index.html", my_audio = created_audio, audio_path = file_path)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run();
```

**html code**

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='audio_path') }}" type="audio/wav"/>
</audio>
```

I need to take audio_path and call it in html.

Comment: Don't you mean `filename=audio_path` (without quotes) ?

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I am new learner sorry :)